# Agregar varios namespace PHP

Tags: php, php7

Trabajo con la biblioteca PhpSpreadSheet y estoy agregando diferentes estilos a las celdas y para hacer que funcione debo agregar los namespace de las clases Alignment, Border, Fill y muchas más de la biblioteca:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
```

**Todo funciona sin ningún problema**

Pero la duda que tengo es ¿se pueden agregar los namespace en general y me refiero como se aplica en Java o C# donde solo agregas `import java.sql.*;` y puedes trabajar con todas sus clases?

Seria para `Style` ya que contiene muchas clases de estaré usado.

¿En caso de que se pueda como seria? o esa es la función que hace el IDE para estos lenguajes?

*Se que el `autoload.php` hace algo similar pero para agregar directamente los archivos `.php`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisamos la documentación de PHP<sup>1</sup>, desde la versión *7.** aquellas clases, constantes y funciones que estén bajo el mismo namespace pueden ser importadas con una única sentencia *`use`*.

De tal modo que esto:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
```

Puede pasar a esto:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\{ Alignment, Border, Fill };
```

**Enlace de referencia**

- <sup>1</sup>[Declaraciones de *`use`* en grupo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group)

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo estaba viendo la documentación pero se me paso ese punto. Ya lo aplique y me sirvió.

Answer (score 1):

En PHP se puede anidar/agrupar los `namespace` que tienen el mismo ámbito por ejemplo:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\ {
    Spreadsheet,
    Writer\Xlsx,
    IOFactory,
    Style\Alignment as Alignment,
    Style\Border as Border,
    Style\Fill as Fill 
}; // Tu ejemplo no puede reproducirse
```

Segun la documentacion [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php) esto tiene soporte desde Desde PHP 7.0